# Why I get this error 'Communications link failure The last packet sent...' when connecting to MySQL with Java (Netbeans)?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, netbeans-7

I am trying to use MySQL database (that is installed on virtual machine (Debian) on my pc and has IP address `192.168.1.5` ) from Java with use of NetBeans.

I have configured the connection as follows :

```
Driver Name MySQL(Connector/J Driver)

Host 192.168.1.5

Database test

Username root

Password *

JDBC URL jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/test
```

and then I get the following error :

```
cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/test using 
  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Communications link failure  The last packet sent successfully 
  to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets 
  from the server.)
```

My `mysql.user` table looks like this ( I know `% root` is not very secure but this is just to simplify things for the moment):

```
+------------+------------------+
| host       | user             |
+------------+------------------+
| %          | root             |
| 127.0.0.1  | root             |
| ::1        | root             |
| debVirtual |                  |
| localhost  |                  |
| localhost  | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost  | phpmyadmin       |
| localhost  | root             |
+------------+------------------+
```

What can I do to allow this connection ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was with mysql configuration file on the server `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

the line : `bind-address`  should point to your server's IP like in this example

`bind-address = 192.168.1.5`

and not

`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

to allow remote access.

Comment: I did all these steps but I still had the problem, finally, I found it was firewalld!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your entire code?

That error comes when the database youre trying to reach does not exist. Check your network setting in your VM software. What type of VM software are you using (VirtualBox, VM ware...)

Answer (score 0):

This is either the wrong folder, or I have a different version. I am running Lubuntu and the file is not my.cnf (because that file does not have a bind-address). the bind-address is situated in a file in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` whose name is: `mysqld.cnf`. You cannot modify it by the file manager so you have to go through the following command lines:

```
sudo su
***enter password***
cd /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
nano mysqld.cnf
```

then go to bind-address 127.0.0.1 and change it to the IPv4 that you can find in

```
ifconfig
```

I hope I helped.

Answer (score -1):

Perfect solution:

1. Start wamp server before netbeans
2. Then open netbeans

It worked for me. When I close the wamp server, it shows me this error: