# MAMP - WSO2 DSS - Error establishing data source connection: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm running MAMP and WSO2 Carbon data service at the same time. What I'm trying to do is adding a new data source by connecting to mysql server. I have added the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to lib folder.

Full error which I'm getting when trying to test the connection

Error establishing data source connection: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with mysql server configuration. Please have a look at following threads.

[Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

[Why I get this error 'Communications link failure The last packet sent...' when connecting to MySQL with Java (Netbeans)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567064/why-i-get-this-error-communicationslinkfailure-thelastpacketsent-when)

[com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121829/mysql-jdbc-communications-link-failure)

Comment: It was the port. It should be 8889 instead of 3306. Thanks for the support anyway.

Answer (score 4):

In my case simply putting **useSSL=false** on end of connection string did the magic

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/USERS?useSSL=false

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it's working by my side:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wso2_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```